# How to hid a text field in CSS when a radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I want when a radio button is checked, some text field shouldn't show. How can I achieve this in CSS or HTML or how can I go about it?

Comment: What do you have so far? Please provide some code. You will most likely need Javascript and/or JQuery.

Comment: This should be possible using adjacent/sibling selectors but we'd need to see your code first.

Comment: What you tried to till now. No one will do coding from sctrach for you ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/

Answer (score 0):

You coul do something like this:

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="input" />
```

**css:**

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked + input {
    display: none;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hrLtq83/